# Axios refresh token got 401

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, refresh-token

I have this code :

```
this.instance.interceptors.response.use(this.handleResponseSuccess, this.handleResponseError.bind(this));
```

Now in handleResponseError I have :

```
handleResponseError(error) {
    if (error && error.response && error.response.status) {
        switch (error.response.status) {
            case 401: 
                return this.401Error(error);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

In function `401Error()` I have :

```
401Error(error) {
    store.dispatch(`auth/refreshToken`).then(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(axios(error.config));
        });
    });
}
```

I check and I have in store the right token, but still I have `401` on the last api called. Any ideas ? Thx in advance